# Let $f(x,y) = cx(1-y) $ for $0<x<y<1$ find the distribtuon of $Z=Y-X$

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $f(x,y) = cx(1-y) $  for  $0<x<y<1$

a) find marginal distributions for $X$ and $Y$

b)find the distribtuon of $Z=Y-X$

so i found c and the marginals:

$c=24$

$f(x)=12x-24x^2+12x^3$

$f(y)=12(y^2-y^3)$

and so $P(Z\leq z)= 1-P(Z>z) = 1 - \int_0^{1-z}\int_{x+z}^{1}f(x,y)dydx$

is there a quicker way to cumpute this using the marginals because when writing it out there seems to be a million steps!

Comment: Can't do it just from the marginals. I think your integral computes $\Pr(Z\gt z)$, and the probability it is $\le$ is $1$ minus your integral.

Comment: how do you use marginals? can you please demonstrate?